# Store images into HDFS, Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I'm using Hadoop 2.5 Vanilla version, I need to store large data set of images into HDFS and Hive but i'm not getting how to do?

Can anyone help to fix this

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To store files into HDFS is easy, see the [put](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put) documentation:

```
Usage: hdfs dfs -put <localsrc> ... <dst>
```

You can write scripts to put the image files in place.

There is another question that tells you how to do it with Hive: [How to Store Binary Data in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257102/how-to-store-binary-data-in-hive)

I see some discussions online that suggest store images to hdfs and store metadata and link to the file in HBase is a better solution than store images directly to HBase.

See following links for reference:

http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/Storing-images-in-Hbase-td4036184.html
http://www.quora.com/Is-HBase-appropriate-for-indexed-blob-storage-in-HDFS
https://www.linkedin.com/groups/What-is-best-NoSQL-DB-3638279.S.5866843079608131586

Comment: where can i find implementation examples for it??

Comment: @MuralikrishnaGS I added some more information. But your own solution needs considering more about what you need.

Comment: @ xgdgsc Thanq for the reply. Im learning Hadoop now a days...my requirement is to **upload a mass data set of images to hive or hbase or may for HDFS and have to retrieve those image for further analysis process**. But didn't get to know how to store it. By using put command i can able to store only a single image at a time.

Comment: @MuralikrishnaGS You can write a shell script to call the put command or use the API to hadoop like https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html and

Comment: ok...thnq...how can i able to retrieve those Sequential files back to its original form?